# Path of least resistance to implement SSO with SAML

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, saml

Here's the environment:

1. Existing .NET B2B application with multiple, external corporate customers. The service provider application is hosted in IIS.
2. Existing non-SSO authentication with user account info stored in a database.
3. Must have both SSO and non-SSO login capability.
4. The initial identity provider will be ADFS hosted by a customer.

All options are on the table. I'm open to cloud solutions, open source (Shibboleth et al), local ADFS server, and/or custom implementation. I'm looking for the easiest and fastest way to implement an SSO solution into an existing .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things to wheigh in. First strike the custom solution part, hard and unnessecary in this case.

As I understand you are looking for the SP part as IDP will be ADFS at customer. 
In this case the product does not even have to talk to the database. Only the IDP needs that.

Some things to think about when choosing the product.

- Opensource is cheep in licens cost. enterprise products can be quite expensive.
- Enterprise product might have better support then opensource when things doenst work. If your applications ar critical this might be important.
- It might be a good idea to consider one of many cloudbased SPs to offload the management of the SP from you.

These are some considerations to take. What you choose will depend on your need and wishes in terms of uptime, support, managements etc.

Most products will have no problem implementing this use case.